# Down casting error (Java). The following code seems to not work, any explanation is appreciated

Tags: java

I recently read up on up casting and down casting and down casting in Java. I tried the following code but it seems to not work.

```
class Super {
    void print() {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    void print() {
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super obj = new Super();
        obj.print();
        Sub obj1 = (Sub) obj;
        obj1.print();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A `Sub` is a `Super`, but a `Super` is not necessarily a `Sub`. In this case, it isn't.

Comment: You're trying to cast a beast to a cow, in other words. You can do `Super sup = new Sub()` and cast that to `Sub`... Because a cow is a beast, and also a cow.

Answer (score 0):

If we take the example of square and rectangle, we know that a square is a rectangle, but a rectangle is not a square. Because in general, casting down loses information, the JVM clearly does not want that to happen, so it causes your program to fail in the Runtime.

Comment: you can cast int to char it is called "narrowing the primitive conversion"

Answer (score 0):

`Subclass` can do anything that `SuperClass` can do, vice versa `SubClass` can implement some methods for its own, thus `Subclass` is not `SuperClass`,`ClassCastException` will be thrown if you invoke casting operator.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a general example , you can apply it anywhere

```
A b = (C)d // here A and C are classes and b and d are references
```

now at compile time the compiler checks 
is the type of `A` and `C` are the same is `C` is child of `A` if any of two condition fails you get compile time error `inconvertable types`

In your case the first condition is true so your code compiles fine.

Now at runtime the JVM checks is underlying type of  `d` is same or is `d` is child of `C` in your case the second condition fails so you get `ClassCastExceptoin`

The downcast you're taking about can happen in case of primitives "it is called narrowing the primitive"